# What's the most efficient way to visit a .html page?

Tags: c#

I have a .html page that *just* has 5 characters on it (4 numbers and a period).

The only way I know of is to make a webbrowser that navigates to a URL, then use

```
browser.GetElementByID();
```

However that uses IE so I'm sure it's slow. Is there any better way (without using an API, something built into C#) to simply visit a webpage in a fashion that you can read off of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these 2 lines:

```
var wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
string html = wc.DownloadString("http://google.com");  // Your page will be in that html variable
```

Comment: Doesn't this essentially make a webbrowser? Isn't that probably the least efficient way of doing it?

Comment: Yes, reads the html content, just like the browser does.Try it!

Comment: So is it efficient? I'll try it, but my computer and internet are both very fast so I probably couldn't tell the difference.

Comment: No browser. WebClient is a convenience wrapper around HttpWebRequest.

Comment: It is more efficient than browser. More closer to the TCP/IP :)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you want to download a url, parse it as html then to find an element and read its inner text, right? Use nuget to grab a reference to HtmlAgilityPack, then:

```
using(var wc = new System.Net.WebClient()){
    string html = wc.DownloadString("http://foo.com");
    var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);
    var el = doc.GetElementbyId("foo");
    if(el != null)
    {
        var text = el.InnerText;
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer, better than mine due to indication of HtmlAgilityPack. (I did not use this library)

Answer (score 0):

Without using *any* APIs? You're in the .NET framework, so you're already using an abstraction layer to some extent. But if you want pure C# without any addons, you could just open a TCP socket to the site and download the contents (it's just a formatted string, after all) and read the data.

Here's a similar question: [How to get page via TcpClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121912/how-to-get-page-via-tcpclient)

Comment: I meant any add-in APIs. Thanks for the idea though.